# How to disable auto-help window appears in TexStudio?

Tags: texstudio

TexStudio is my favourite Tex editor. However, one feature is very annoying that I couldn't figure out how to disable. When the mouse pointer stays for a while on some Tex command, an auto-help window appears on the screen which includes information about the command. I tried to disable it from `options`, `configure TeXstudio`, but it seems that there is no option there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is. You have to check the Advanced Options. See the image.

[image]

Then, the Special Options contains the Help tooltips.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice the "Show Advanced Options".

Comment: As of now, the option 'Show preview as tooltip on formulas in editor' is absent and it is not clear how to disable the preview.

Comment: In version 2.2.16 this option has moved to the "Preview" section in options.