# How to Disable Text-Help Pop-Ups in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

While typing in TeXstudio, I often get the following (annoying) pop-up notification.

[image: Pop-up Example]

I have disabled various things in the advanced options (everything that looks relevant to me)...

(See [How to disable auto-help window appears in TexStudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141141/how-to-disable-auto-help-window-appears-in-texstudio) for a related question; my snippet below shows that I have done as suggested there -- at least, I think I have!)

[image: Advanced Options]

However, they still appears. They're super annoying, offering me almost no benefit and yet get in the way frequently.
How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Goto tab "completion" and disable the two tooltips check buttons in the upper right corner.  For older versions there is only one Tooltip button.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks! +1 \\ Because of the tooltip in "Adv. Editor", I didn't think about there being one in "Completion". (I'll accept in 4mins when I'm allowed to...)

Comment: This did not work for me. TeXstudio seems to have updated just now, because the tooltips started appearing (have been removed for years before). Unchecking the boxes did nothing for me.

Comment: @SanderHeinsalu: I have version "TeXstudio 2.12.22 (git 2.12.22)" for macOS

Comment: @SanderHeinsalu This didn't do the trick for me either. I had to follow the steps in the linked question (see original question).

Comment: So what had I disabled earlier... ? [laugh]